# Why can't I create a new Color?

Tags: java, colors

Problem solved : Used wrong Color Package

I am trying to read some values from an csv file, and when I put three of the numbers together, they form an rgb-value.

However, for some reason, my IDE, Netbeans, is giving me the error:
'new Color(float,float,float) has private access in the class Color'

I have no idea how using parseInt can yield a float, even after casting the result to an integer as well.

Thank you for your time and patience.

```
    public void initBasicRGB(String definitionCSVContent) {
    String[] lines = definitionCSVContent.split("\n");
    String[] values;
    for (String s : lines) {
        values = s.split(";");
        if (!s.isEmpty() && values.length==6 ) {
            int red = (int)Integer.parseInt(values[1]);
            int green = (int)Integer.parseInt(values[2]);
            int blue = (int)Integer.parseInt(values[3]);
            String nameProvince = values[4];
            basicRGB.put(new Color(red,green,blue), nameProvince);
//the error is on the line above
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: where is basicRGB located?

Comment: post your entire class

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem. Are you using `Color` from `java.awt` package or from somewhere else (maybe you created your own `Color` class)? Also `new Color(red,green,blue)` should use `Color(int r, int g, int b)`, not `new Color(float,float,float)` since `red`, `green` and `blue` are integers.

Comment: Im writing my program in FX and imported an fx color package (from paint) I switched it up to regular awt.Color package and now it works. Thx !

Comment: Using the wrong `Color` class seems like a likely explanation.  Try to put together an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) - not only will this help us debug your problem, but it's always a good first step for helping *you* debug your own problems.

Comment: If you've solved your problem in a way you think may help others, then please do post it as an answer.

Comment: It was a silly oversight ,nothing contemplative worthy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used a package from awt instead of fx